# execute multiple chef cookbooks locally in windows

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

How to run chefclient locally with multiple cookbooks?
Forexample, the following line throws error

```
chef-client -z -o "recipe[cookbook1::default],recipe[cookbook2::default]"
```

> error : Net::HTTPServerException: 412 "Precondition Failed"

How to run multiple cookbook recipes locally in Windows?

Comment: `chef-client -z -o "cookbook1,cookbook2"` should do if the cookbooks are in the proper path, a full log would be better to undertstand what is failing

Answer (score 1):

The following line worked

chef-client -z --runlist 'recipe[cookbook1::default],recipe[cookbook2::default],recipe[cookbook3::default],recipe[cookbook4::default]'

Comment: Please mark as the selected answer, this worked for me as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When using solo or local mode, you need to handle getting the cookbook code deployed yourself, chef doesn't handle it. This is why we recommend using normal chef-client for most users, since that provides a whole bunch of workflow machinery to handle this task. But for solo or local mode, it's up to you :) most people use `berks vendor` or `chef export`.